# Typescript: No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type

Tags: typescript

I am trying to access a property on an imported object in the following manner:

```js
import * as reducers from './reducers';

const reducer = reducers[rule.reducer.name](rule.reducer.args);
```

Elsewhere my reducers are defined as follows:

```js
export const sum = (property: string) => (pageViews: IPageView[]): number =>
  pageViews.reduce((acc, pageView) => Number(acc + pageView[property]), 0);
```

I also have the following type definitions:

```
export interface IPageView {
  features: object;
}

interface IConditionQuery {
  property: string;
  value?: any;
}

interface IConditionRule {
  reducer?: {
    name: string;
    args?: any;
  };
  matcher?: {
    name: string;
    args: any;
  };
}

export interface ICondition {
  filter: {
    any: boolean;
    queries: IConditionQuery[];
  };
  rules: IConditionRule[];
}
```

So I understand the problem (i think) that I could be accessing a `reducer` which does not exist since I am passing in a `string`, I am not sure at all how I would go about fixing this.

What I have tried is hardcoding various forms of `enums` with no luck.

EDIT:
Full error message

```
semantic error TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'typeof import("/Users/dennisyurkevich/dev/edkt/engine/src/reducers")'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'typeof import("/Users/dennisyurkevich/dev/edkt/engine/src/reducers")'.
```

Comment: Was found on *which* type? Please add the full error message. We need to know *what* happened and *where*.

Comment: Added now @AndreasDolk

Comment: Most of the code like the `sum` function or all the interfaces doesn't seem to be related to the problem. How did you define `reducers`? Can you show that? And you didn't show, where the error occurs, I assume on the second line in you first code snippet?